# How to pass a parameter to a shared dagger module?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm trying to get multiple dagger modules to share a single common module, where the common module needs access to a different string based on which module included it.

*Note that even though in the example code below, I'm passing in a single string (for simplicity), I actually want to pass in multiple strings*

```
// The shared module
@Module()
public final class SharedModule {
  @Provides @Singleton
  public static SomeClass(String moduleSpecificString) {
    return new SomeClass(moduleSpecificString);
  }
}

// Two modules trying to use the shared module, but where each 
// module needs the shared module to be using a slightly different 
// parameter

@Module(includes = {SharedModule.class))
public final class ModuleA {
  @Provides @Singleton
  public static String moduleTextA() {
    return "ModuleA"
  }
}

@Module(includes = {SharedModule.class))
public final class ModuleB {
  @Provides @Singleton
  public static String moduleTextA() {
    return "ModuleB"
  }
}
```

The two potential solutions I've found so far are:

1. Use @BindsInstance to specify the Strings in the component builder instead

But that has the downside of moving these hardcoded strings out of the module (meaning every test that tries to build just the module now has to also declare those strings)

2. Use @IntoMap in ModuleA and ModuleB to insert the string into a map.

This lets me use the same map to pass in multiple strings, but it seems like I loose dagger's compile time checks to ensure that every Key in the map which I care about actually has a value defined.

Are there any better options out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules can take constructor arguments: This would require that your SharedModule is a class and that anything that interacts with your constructor argument would be necessarily non-static. Rather than using @BindsInstance you would need your Component Builder/Factory to accept an instance of your Module that you create, because in absence of a public parameterless constructor Dagger won't even try. (That, of course, also allows you to use static factory methods, Builders, or any other sort of interface you choose.)

```java
@Module()
public final class SharedModule {
  private final String moduleSpecificString;

  public SharedModule(String moduleSpecificString /*, ... */) {
    this.moduleSpecificString = moduleSpecificString;
    // ...
  }

  @Provides @Singleton
  public /* non-static */ SomeClass provideSomeClass() {
    return new SomeClass(moduleSpecificString);
  }
}

// elsewhere
YourComponent yourComponent =
    YourComponent.builder()
        .sharedModule(new SharedModule("magic"))
        // ...
        .build();
```

You could also subclass: you can make your SharedModule abstract and have ModuleA and ModuleB inherit from it, so ModuleA and ModuleB have parameterless constructors that call `super` with your magic string. If you go this way, proceed carefully: One advantage of Dagger's Module.includes is that it will de-duplicate included modules, so if ModuleX and ModuleY both install ModuleZ, Dagger won't complain about ModuleZ appearing multiple times. By contrast, if SharedModule has bindings it exposes, ModuleA and ModuleB would be more-or-less guaranteed not to be able to exist in the same component because that shared binding would be a necessarily duplicate binding between ModuleA and ModuleB. There are a number of other downsides to module subclassing that Dagger lists on its [testing guidebook page](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/testing#do-not-override-bindings-by-subclassing-modules).

Finally, if you do need ModuleA and ModuleB to coexist with different magic strings, you might consider [subcomponents for encapsulation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/subcomponents#subcomponents-for-encapsulation). Rather than ModuleA and ModuleB exposing the same bindings, you would define a SharedComponent that includes SharedModule and pass the specific bindings back out to the outer main graph.